# Re-factor of code in Rails 2.3 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, refactoring, controller

I have a fairly simple Rails application that allows users to manage their clients and create a case for each client. When a case is created the details are sent to two email addresses (different content in each email) and using a gem, sends the information to *`FreeagentCentral`*.

I have implemented *`delayed_job`* which is working well for the *`Freeagent API`* call, but I think there is probably a better, lower overhead, method of sending the emails. It seems to take quite a while.

I currently have the following code in my Rails 2.3 application.

**kases_controller.rb**

```
# POST /kases
# POST /kases.xml
  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
    @kase = @company.kases.new(params[:kase])

    if @kase.save
        UserMailer.deliver_makeakase("dropbox@1223111.domain.highrisehq.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:sendtohighrise]
        UserMailer.deliver_makeakaseteam("surveymanager@domain.co.uk", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
        @kase.delay.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent]

        redirect_to(@kase)

        #flash[:notice] = 'Case was successfully created.'
        flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Case was successfully created.", 5)
      else
        render :new
      end        
  end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def makeakase(email, name, kase, bccemails = [])
      recipients email
      from "info@domain.co.uk"
      subject "FW: Case creation from Survey Manager"
      bcc bccemails
      sent_on Time.now
      body :name => name, :kase => kase
  end

  def makeakaseteam(email, name, kase = [])
      recipients email
      from "info@domain.co.uk"
      subject "A new case has been created."
      sent_on Time.now
      body :name => name, :kase => kase
      content_type "text/html"
  end
```

I am looking for any advice on slimming down the number of emails sent, or a way of adding the emails to the delayed jobs.

I use PostmarkApp for sending the emails, which is another gem. Details of which can be found here: [postmark-gem](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-gem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but i would make a method that would do the sending of the emails and the creation of the freeagent, and then let it be handled by delayed_job.

Something like

```
class Kase

  def send_emails(current_user, send_to_highrise, notify_team, send_to_freeagent)
    UserMailer.deliver_makeakase("dropbox@1223111.domain.highrisehq.com", "Highrise", self) if send_to_highrise
    UserMailer.deliver_makeakaseteam("surveymanager@domain.co.uk", "Highrise", self) if notify_team
    self.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if send_to_freeagent
  end
end
```

and in your controller you would then write

```
if @kase.save
  @kase.delay.send_emails(current_user, params[:sendtohighrise], 
                         params[:notify_team_of_creation], params[:send_to_freeagent])
  redirect_to @kase
  flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Case was successfully created.", 5)
else
  ...
```

or just handing down the `params` is maybe simpler/cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Starling and Workling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling) for a similar problem. I'm not sure if this is a lower overhead as I've personally never used `delayed_job` yet. You may want to explore it.

Answer (score 0):

With delayed_job installed, for older versions you should be able to simply do the following.

```
UserMailer.send_later(:deliver_makeakase, "dropbox@1223111.domain.highrisehq.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:sendtohighrise]
UserMailer.send_later(:deliver_makeakaseteam, "surveymanager@domain.co.uk", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
```

For version starting at 2.0.4 the syntax is a bit different.

```
UserMailer.delay.deliver_makeakase("dropbox@1223111.domain.highrisehq.com", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:sendtohighrise]
UserMailer.delay.deliver_makeakaseteam("surveymanager@domain.co.uk", "Highrise", @kase) if params[:notify_team_of_creation]
```

Comment: Isn't the send_later option only available with Rails 3 and delayed_job?

Comment: send_later is actually older deprecated syntax. And I'm using that syntax in my rails 2 app, since I have older version of the gem.